# How do I retrieve name of a layer inside hook function?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a neural network

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.trunk = nn.ModuleList()
    self.trunk.add_module('conv1', nn.Conv2d(3, 10, 3))

    self.classifier = nn.Linear(30, 2)
  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.classifier(self.trunk.conv1(x))
    return out

model = ConvNet()
```

I registered forward hook

```
def hook(module, input, output):
    print(module, input[0].shape, output.shape)

x =  model.trunk.conv1.register_forward_hook(hook)
```

How do I retrieve name of this layer that is 'conv1' inside hook function, `module._get_name` returns `Conv2d`, `module.__class__` returns `<class 'torch.nn.modules.conv.Conv2d'>`, how do I get just 'conv1'?

Comment: May I ask what is your end goal? There probably is/should be easier way for what you want to do, as it seems this information is already in your code, but you are approaching it from a strange side. Maybe you want the hook to only execute on specific layer with specific name?

Comment: I have multiple neural networks, and want to plot features on tensorboard.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is pass the layer name from outside.

Rewrite your hook function like this:

```
def get_activation(name):
  def hook(module, input, output):
      print("layer name", name)
      print("output", output)
  return hook
```

So you can use it easily when you iterate the layers:

```
for name, layer in model.named_modules():
  layer.register_forward_hook(get_activation(name))
```